# how should i make a async call from my controller to my interface

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an interface :

```
 public IEnumerable<statisticsDaily> statsMonthly(string id, string dtFrom, string dtTo)
    {

        var rslt =  ( from d in db.statMonth
                    join s in db.masterData on d.m_turbine_id equals s.m_turbine_id
                    where d.m_turbine_id == IPAddress.Parse(id) && d.m_date >= frm
                    group d by d.m_date.Month into g
                    select new statisticsDaily
                    {
                        Date = g.Key.ToString("MMM"),
                        Production = g.Sum(s => s.m_energy_prod),
                        m_wind_speed = g.Average(s => s.m_wind_speed),
                        Availability = g.Average(s => s.m_availability)

                    }
             ).AsEnumerable(); 

        return rslt;


    }
```

I have a controller which should perform async call:

```
   public async Task StaticsMonthly(string id, string from, string to)
    {
       _statdaily.statsMonthly(id, startDate.ToString(), now.ToString()));
        return Ok( result);
    }
```

this gives me an error Severity Code
Error   CIEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your action method as synchronous as it's doesn't doing any asynchronous work and not returning Task object which is causing the exception

This should work

```
public IActionResult StaticsMonthly(string id, string from, string to)
    {
       _statdaily.statsMonthly(id, startDate.ToString(), now.ToString()));
        return Ok( result);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but with IActionresult i dont get Async advantage right?

Comment: You are not using any async call in the code, so marking the action method async won't give you any advantage

Answer (score 0):

Make that your statsMonthly function should return a task:

```
public async<Task<IEnumerable<statisticsDaily>>> statsMonthly(string id, string dtFrom, string dtTo)
{

    var rslt = await ( from d in db.statMonth
                join s in db.masterData on d.m_turbine_id equals s.m_turbine_id
                where d.m_turbine_id == IPAddress.Parse(id) && d.m_date >= frm
                group d by d.m_date.Month into g
                select new statisticsDaily
                {
                    Date = g.Key.ToString("MMM"),
                    Production = g.Sum(s => s.m_energy_prod),
                    m_wind_speed = g.Average(s => s.m_wind_speed),
                    Availability = g.Average(s => s.m_availability)

                }
         ).ToListAsync(); 

    return rslt;


}
```

Then is your controller await the function:

```
 public async Task StaticsMonthly(string id, string from, string to)
{
   var results = await _statdaily.statsMonthly(id, startDate.ToString(), now.ToString()));
    return Ok( result);
}
```